# Trigger ng-show after delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-timeout

I want to make a div appear 10s after the page has loaded. I would like to use angular.

```
<div class="appearingitem" ng-show="timeduration"></div>
```

Any ideas how i might accomplish this? Is there any way to trigger, say a function after a set time? I feel like this should be easy, and i've tried googleing but since i'm new to programming I don't know exactly what I'm looking for

Thank you

Comment: you can use timeout for this

Answer (score 1):

`$timeout` would help you in this case, by executing desired code in callback with specified `timeout` in milliseconds.

**Code**

```
$scope.timeduration = true; //showing some element
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.timeduration = false; //hiding after 10 secs
}, 10000);
```

Make sure you should inject `$timeout` dependency on your controller factory function before using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('app', []).
factory('timeduration',function($timeout,$q){
    var timeduration = false;            
    $timeout(function(){//Simulate a request
        timeduration = true;
    },2000);
    return timeduration;
}).
controller('root',function($scope,timeduration){

    $scope.timeduration = timeduration;

});

<div class="appearingitem" ng-show="timeduration">
      // which you want to show here after delay
</div>
```

**div show after 2 sec** you can change your time instead of 2000 which you want.

Hope its help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the $timeout Service:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

```
$scope.showItem = false
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.showItem = true;
}, 10000); // Time in ms
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   $scope.display = function(){
     $scope.timeduration=false; 
     $timeout(function () {
        $scope.timeduration= true;
      }, 10000); 
  }
```